# mysql index is not use in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query,

```sql
select u.*
from `usage` as u 
  use index (index4,index7)
where u.IsDeleted = 0
and (
  (p_fromDate is null and p_toDate is null) or
  (p_fromDate is not null and p_toDate is not null and
    DATE(CONCAT(
      convert(u.`Year`, char(4)), 
      '-', 
      convert(u.`Month`, char(2)), '-1'
    )) between p_fromDate and p_toDate
  ) or
  (
    p_fromDate is not null and 
    p_toDate is not null and 
    u.`Month` is null and
    u.`Year` between Year(p_fromDate) and Year(p_toDate)
  )
)
```

Which I want to add index to improve the performance, I have add two index.

create index index4 on `usage` (IsDeleted);

The above one is for `u.IsDeleted = 0`, which I can see is used in `EXPLAIN`.

The following one I created is I want the `Year` can be used in the second evaluation of the `where` clause

`create index index7 on`usage`(Year);`

This is the second evaluation of the `where` clause

```sql
(p_fromDate is null and p_toDate is null) or
(
  p_fromDate is not null and p_toDate is not null
  and DATE(CONCAT(
    convert(u.`Year`, char(4)), 
    '-', 
    convert(u.`Month`, char(2)), 
    '-1'
  )) between p_fromDate and p_toDate
) or
(
  p_fromDate is not null and p_toDate is not null
  and u.`Month` is null
  and u.`Year` between Year(p_fromDate) and Year(p_toDate)
)
```

But in the `EXPLAIN`

```sql
    # id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
    1, SIMPLE, u, , ref, index4,index7, index4, 1, const, 37547, 100.00, Using where
```

You can see only index4 is used, index7 of `year` is not used for second condition, can I make the query use index for second condition in where clause?

Sample data

```
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | LocationID | IndicatorID | Year | Month | HalfYear1 | HalfYear2 | FourMonths1 | FourMonths2 | FourMonths3 | Q1   | Q2   | Q3   | Q4   | BiMonthly1 | BiMonthly2 | BiMonthly3 | BiMonthly4 | BiMonthly5 | BiMonthly6 | DateOfUsage | Price | PriceUnit | ExchangeRate | Value | ValueUnit | Remarks | CreatedBy                    | CreatedDate         | ModifiedBy                   | ModifiedDate        | IsDeleted | IsHeatRecovery |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 1  | 33         | 17          | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | 33         | 15          | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 3  | 33         | 653         | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 4  | 34         | 17          | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 5  | 34         | 15          | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 6  | 34         | 653         | 2016 | 4     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 7  | 33         | 17          | 2016 | 5     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 8  | 33         | 15          | 2016 | 5     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 9  | 33         | 653         | 2016 | 5     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 10 | 34         | 17          | 2016 | 5     | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      | NULL         | NULL  | kg        | NULL    | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | john.smith@hkg.fujixerox.com | 2017-07-11 17:23:28 | 0         | 0              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Result of running the original stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SelectUsage4`(

      IN p_ids MEDIUMTEXT
    , IN p_locationIDs MEDIUMTEXT
    , IN p_indicatorIDs MEDIUMTEXT
    , IN p_fromDate date
    , IN p_toDate date
    , IN p_yearly tinyint(4)
    , IN p_monthly tinyint(4)
    , IN p_halfYear1 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_halfYear2 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_fourMonths1 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_fourMonths2 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_fourMonths3 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_q1 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_q2 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_q3 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_q4 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly1 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly2 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly3 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly4 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly5 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_biMonthly6 tinyint(4)
    , IN p_approvalStatus int(11)
    , IN p_language nvarchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    explain select 
        case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = l.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'locations' and lbl.ColumnName = 'LocationName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language) > 0 then
            (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = l.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'locations' and lbl.ColumnName = 'LocationName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language limit 1)
        else
            l.LocationName
        end as LocationName
        , l.ParentID as LocationParentID
        , l.Active as LocationActive
        , l.RegionID
        , case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = i.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'indicators' and lbl.ColumnName = 'IndicatorName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language) > 0 then
            (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = i.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'indicators' and lbl.ColumnName = 'IndicatorName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language limit 1)
        else
            i.IndicatorName
        end as IndicatorName
        , i.ParentID as IndicatorParentID
        , i.Unit
        , i.DecimalPlaces
        , i.Active as IndicatorActive
        , i.IndicatorType
        , u.*
    from
        `usage` as u
        left join `locations` as l on u.LocationID = l.id
        left join `Indicators` as i on u.IndicatorID = i.id
    where
        u.IsDeleted = 0
        and (
            (p_fromDate is null and p_toDate is null)
            or
            (
                p_fromDate is not null and p_toDate is not null
                and
                DATE(CONCAT(convert(u.`Year`, char(4)), '-', convert(u.`Month`, char(2)), '-1')) between p_fromDate and p_toDate
            )
            or
            (
                p_fromDate is not null and p_toDate is not null
                and
                u.`Month` is null
                and
                u.`Year` between Year(p_fromDate) and Year(p_toDate)
            )
        )
        and (p_yearly is null or (p_yearly is not null and p_yearly = 1 and u.`Month` is null) or (p_yearly is not null and p_yearly = 0 and u.`Month` is not null))
        and (p_monthly is null or (p_monthly is not null and p_monthly = 1 and u.`Month` is not null))
        and (p_ids is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.id, p_ids))
        and (p_locationIDs is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.LocationID, p_locationIDs))
        and (p_indicatorIDs is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.IndicatorID, p_indicatorIDs))
        and
        (

               (p_halfYear1 is null or u.HalfYear1 = p_halfYear1)
            or (p_halfYear2 is null or u.HalfYear2 = p_halfYear2)
        )
        and
        (
               (p_fourMonths1 is null or u.FourMonths1 = p_fourMonths1)
            or (p_fourMonths2 is null or u.FourMonths2 = p_fourMonths2)
            or (p_fourMonths3 is null or u.FourMonths3 = p_fourMonths3)
        )
        and
        (
               (p_q1 is null or u.Q1 = p_q1)
            or (p_q2 is null or u.Q2 = p_q2)
            or (p_q3 is null or u.Q3 = p_q3)
            or (p_q4 is null or u.Q4 = p_q4)
        )
        and
        (
               (p_biMonthly1 is null or u.BiMonthly1 = p_biMonthly1)
            or (p_biMonthly2 is null or u.BiMonthly2 = p_biMonthly2)
            or (p_biMonthly3 is null or u.BiMonthly3 = p_biMonthly3)
            or (p_biMonthly4 is null or u.BiMonthly4 = p_biMonthly4)
            or (p_biMonthly5 is null or u.BiMonthly5 = p_biMonthly5)
            or (p_biMonthly6 is null or u.BiMonthly6 = p_biMonthly6)
        )
        and (
                p_approvalStatus is null
                or
                (
                    select ara.ApprovalStatus
                    from `tasks_details` as t
                    inner join `approval_request_tasks` as art on t.TaskID = art.TaskID
                    inner join `approval_request_approvers` as ara on art.ApprovalRequestID = ara.ApprovalRequestID
                    where
                        t.IsDeleted = 0 
                        and 
                        t.ObjectID = u.id
                        and t.ObjectType = 'Usage'
                    order by
                        ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                ) = p_approvalStatus
            )
    order by
        i.IndicatorName, l.LocationName
;

END
```

And here is the result

Comment: MySQL *generally* does not use more than one index at a time. Unless, it is a UNION / simple OR conditions; or it is a subquery, which basically is a select of its own.

Comment: Your query is a bit convoluted; it would be better if this query can be rewritten in another way, in order to be able to use better indexes. Please provide some minimal sample data and expected output showcasing all the cases. A fiddle would be helpful as well. Read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: I have some rows selected, but I want to format the result with lines and plus sign like box. How can I do that?

Comment: Check https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables . Read this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks. Is the information I provided enough?

Comment: Stored Procedure is way too complex to grasp; One suggestion is to convert `OR` to UNION based queries; that way MySQL can pick the indexes for different select queries individually.

Comment: so how can I handle the ```and``` condition? Anyway that I can convert it?